# OpenCV installed but not linked error message on OS-X Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, opencv, homebrew, osx-mavericks

When I give the following command

```
brew install homebrew/science/opencv
```

or

```
brew install opencv
```

I get the following message.

```
Warning: opencv-2.4.7.1 already installed, it's just not linked
```

Any idea how to fix this. 
I already have the following in the `.bash_profile` based on the links.

[Installing openCV 2.4.2 on Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707468/installing-opencv-2-4-2-on-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks)

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.6.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

[Linking Python with Open CV on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724083/linking-python-with-open-cv-on-mac)

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

When I do a link using the following command, I get the following error.

```
$brew link opencv
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1... Warning: Could not link opencv. Unlinking...

Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.7.1/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig is not writable. You should change its permissions.
```

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Thanks.

Comment: I followed this link to fix the issue. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with brew link --overwrite --dry-run opencv

Comment: I dont understand, I thought the dry run doesnt actually change anything. I tried it and like it displayed what the changes would be but the error is still there

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem by use

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

then 

`brew link numpy`

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem. And by following the post mentioned above, I solve the problem through a series of `chown` command suggested by `brew doctor`.
Here is what I got when I use `brew doctor`

```
Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

    /usr/local/share/man/de
    /usr/local/share/man/de/man1
    /usr/local/share/man/mann
```

So I change the own of these folders.

After that I use `brew link --overwrite opencv`

Now when I type brew link opencv, it shows

```
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.11
To relink: brew unlink opencv && brew link opencv
```

I think it works.

Answer (score 0):

I run 'brew doctor' and then just followed the brew doctor instructions