# Opencv not working for python?

Tags: python, opencv

When ever I say import cv2 and run in IDLE it gives me an error saying:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/Victor/Documents/Python Related/Python Code for
>   Class/blah.py", line 2, in 
>       import cv2 ImportError: No module named 'cv2'

But when ever I run  "brew install opencv"  on my Terminal it says:

> Warning: homebrew/science/opencv-2.4.13.2 already installed, it's just
>   not linked.

Which I am taking it as Opencv is already installed. I have no idea why it wont work when I run it in python. I have followed this [link](https://jjyap.wordpress.com/2014/05/24/installing-opencv-2-4-9-on-mac-osx-with-python-support/)  and 
I also used this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html#ios-installation).

but that did not seem to help much. I have spent all day on trying to make this work ...

Wanted to see if anyone who has experience with OpenCV can give me a bit of guidance. It is definitely not as simple as installing pygame or other models.

Comment: There are some possible answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140953/opencv-installed-but-not-linked-error-message-on-os-x-mavericks

Answer (score 1):

Try `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python{version}/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH`

Comment: @felipsmartins A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)